# Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. in android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had an Android project built with Android Studio and trying to import and run it on my Android Studio but facing the below error when trying to Sync the project

```
Failed to sync Gradle project 'project-android'

Error:Gradle version 1.10 is required. Current version is 2.2.1. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in /Users/username/apps/android/project-android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-1.10-all.zip.

Please fix the project's Gradle settings in Gradle settings
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


Android Studio Version : 1.0.1
```

So how to fix the above error

**Edit**

After changing the lines as indicated by @Grabiele i was getting the below errors

```
Error:(22, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard()'
Possible causes: 
The project 'project-android' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
```

This is the line that i had in `app/build.gradle` file

```
 buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Comment: change   `runProguard false`  to `minifyEnabled false`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to update the:

- gradle plugin for Android
- gradle version
- proguard syntax

**Gradle plugin for Android**

You have to change this line in `build.gradle`:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
```

in

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.+'
```

**Gradle Version**

Change this line in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

in

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
```

About **proguard** you have to change this line in your `build.gradle`

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

In

```
buildTypes {
        release {
             minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
```

Comment: @shivakrishna updated the answer with the proguard part

Comment: Ok i updated the question, because i also had proguardFiles setting as above, so what to do in these situations

Comment: Updated. Just said before you have to change 'runProguard false'  
to 'minifyEnabled false'

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this!

Answer (score 1):

addition to @Gabriele answer

you should change

```
runProguard false
```

to

```
minifyEnabled false
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just used

> "Menu > File > Invalidate Caches/Restart > Invalidate & Restart"

I was solved.