# Different Gradle versions in my project? (gradle.xml vs build.gradle)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

in gradle.xml i have version 2.4 ( **C:\Development\android-studio\gradle\gradle-2.4** ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="GradleSettings">
    <option name="linkedExternalProjectsSettings">
      <GradleProjectSettings>
        <option name="distributionType" value="LOCAL" />
        <option name="externalProjectPath" value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
        <option name="gradleHome" value="C:\Development\android-studio\gradle\gradle-2.4" />
        <option name="gradleJvm" value="1.8" />
        <option name="modules">
          <set>
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/caponateLibrary" />
            <option value="$PROJECT_DIR$/launcher" />
          </set>
        </option>
      </GradleProjectSettings>
    </option>
  </component>
</project>
```

But in my Project uild.gradle file i have 1.3.0:

```
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
```

Why these files have different gradle versions? Which differences does exists between these two gradle versions and which is the real gradle version?

Thanks

Comment: The first one is the gradle distribution. The second one is the android plugin for gradle. Check for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29346593/gradle-version-1-10-is-required-current-version-is-2-2-1-in-android/29346664#29346664

Comment: OK, thanks, but, then, why gradle is storing a lot of cache content in this directory (2.2.1)? C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts

Comment: It is the gradle distribution 2.2.1. In an old project may be you were using the 2.2.1

Comment: then, where are being stored my new cache files? i can't find them

Comment: Check the .gradle\wrapper\dists and the .gradle\cache folders

Comment: ummmm something is very wrong here, my 2.2.1 folder is still being filled with cache files each time i do assembleRelease... what is happening here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102996/discussion-between-gabriele-mariotti-and-nullpointerexception).

Comment: To know the distribution that you are using in the project check the gradle/ gradle-wrapper.properties inside the project.

Comment: i'm chatting, please read the chat

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't confuse **gradle distribution** and the **android plugin for gradle**.

1) You can define the gradle distribution used by a project in the file
 `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`

For example:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.4-all.zip
```

Each project can use a different version. You will find the distributions file inside `\user\.gradle\wrapper\dists` folder.

2) Gradle is a build tool, but it requires specific plugin to work.
Android Tool Team is releasing the Android plugin for Gradle.

You can define the plugin inside the build.gradle file in the project.

For example:

```
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
```

Each project (or module) can use a different version.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is actual gradle binaries, and hence actual gradle version. The second is (IMO) unfortunately named, and isn't gradle at all. It is android plugin for gradle and its version.

Comment: OK, thanks, but, then, why gradle is storing a lot of cache content in this directory? 
C:/Windows/System32/config/systemprofile/.gradle/caches/2.2.1/scripts